# Post data on a forum programatically

Tags: tcp, libcurl

can you send data using libcurl on forum or any other ways like TCP/IP API?

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://site.com/forum
```

inspect the page source for form field names. With libcurl you would use With libcurl, you can build the form with curl_formadd().